# $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

Define the sequence $(a_n)$ as following $a_1=1$ for $n\geq 1$ $a_{n+1}=(-1)^n(1/2)(|a_n|+2/|a_n|)$ which of the following

(1) $\lim \sup a_n=\sqrt{2}$

(2) $\lim \inf a_n=-\infty$

(3) $\lim a_n=\sqrt{2}$

(4) $\sup a_n =\sqrt{2}$

I am not getting how to obtain $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$...
I tried getting some terms if the sequence $a_1=1,a_2=-\frac{3}{2},a_3=\frac{17}{12}..$ but unable to conclude anything ...just all the terms are less then 2... only this I can conclude

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It may help to first look at the sequence $b_1 = 1$ and $b_{n+1} = \frac12(b_n + 2/b_n)$ (this sequence is a little better behaved).  Then note that $a_n = (-1)^{n-1}b_n$.